# How To Configure Docker in Magento 2 In Local System?

Tags: magento2, docker

Provide Step For How To Configure Docker in Magento 2 In Local System?

Comment: you want to setup for existing project or new one ?

Comment: Bot existing and new setup step.

Answer (score 0):

there are many solutions that can help you with that if you have experience with docker before

use this solution works well for both Mac and Linux

[repository with docker images and well define steps](https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento)